# What exactly does React.createElement accept as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) say that its takes a type, but in the below 2 examples, they both work, with the first example actually taking a function. Doesn't this mean the docs are wrong? Seems like `createElement` not only takes a type with, but also a function that returns an element. That to me feels tricky.

```
var title = function (props) {
  return (
    React.createElement(
      'h1',
      null,
      'title'
    )
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(title),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

VS.

```
var title = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  null,
  'title'
)

ReactDOM.render(
  title,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: The next line reads: *"The type argument can be either a tag name string (such as `'div'` or `'span'`), or a React component type (a class or a function)."*

Comment: @AndrewLi: You can write an answer :)

Comment: @FelixKling sure, I'll go ahead and post one

Answer (score 2):

The [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) also states this on the next line:

> The type argument can be either a tag name string (such as `'div'` or `'span'`), or a [React component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) type (a class or a function).

So you can pass a string as the type, which creates native elements such as `div` or `h1`:

```
React.createElement('h1', null, 'title');
```

You can also pass a function as the first argument *that is a React component*:

```
var title = function (props) {
  return (
    React.createElement(
      'h1',
      null,
      'title'
    )
  );
};

React.createElement(title);
```

Here, `title` is *a React component*, more specifically a *functional component* so you can create an element with that type.